# Unable to resolve error on whmcs template due invoice

Tags: php, whmcs

Hi I am trying to make code for whmcs temple got error may be  i am wrong somewhere please help me Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in /home/demoqual/public_html/shop/templates_c/2a8fc6217554834b90dbc0a7559c2223^%%AC^ACC^ACC45BED%%emailtpl%3Aemailmessage.php on line 5

```
Dear {$client_name} Please find the list of all unpaid invoices at QualiSpace {php} $client_id= $_REQUEST['userid']; $result = mysql_query('SELECT I.*, II.description FROM tblinvoices I LEFT JOIN tblinvoiceitems II ON (I.id = II.invoiceid) WHERE I.userid= '.$client_id.' AND I.status=\'Unpaid\' ORDER BY I.id DESC'); $i = 0; while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { $id = $data['id']; $invoicenum = $data['invoicenum']; $date = $data['date']; $duedate = $data['duedate']; $total = $data['total']; $description = $data['description']; $status = $data['status']; $date = frommysqldate ($date); $duedate = frommysqldate ($duedate); if (!$invoicenum) { $invoicenum = $id; } $invoices[$i]['id'] = $id; $invoices[$i]['invoicenum'] = $invoicenum; $invoices[$i]['invoicedate'] = $date; $invoices[$i]['datedue'] = $duedate; $invoices[$i]['total'] = $total; $invoices[$i]['description'] = $description; //$invoices[$i]['status'] = getinvoicestatuscolour ($status); $invoices[$i]['status'] = $status; ++$i; } $smartyvalues["invoices"] = $invoices; //echo "
<pre>";print_r($smartyvalues);echo "</pre>
"; $count = 1; $grandTotal = 0; echo ""; echo ""; for($i=0;$i&lt;COUNT($smartyvalues["invoices"]);$i++) { echo ""; $grandTotal += $smartyvalues["invoices"][$i]["total"]; $count++; } echo ""; echo "
<table border="1">
<tbody>
<tr><th>No.</th><th>Invoice No.</th><th>Invoice Date</th><th>Due Date</th><th>Particular</th><th>Status</th><th>Amount</th></tr>
<tr> 
<td>".$count."</td>
<td>#".$smartyvalues["invoices"][$i]["invoicenum"]."</td>
<td>".$smartyvalues["invoices"][$i]["invoicedate"]."</td>
<td>".$smartyvalues["invoices"][$i]["datedue"]."</td>
<td>".$smartyvalues["invoices"][$i]["description"]."</td>
<td>".$smartyvalues["invoices"][$i]["status"]."</td>
<td>".$smartyvalues["invoices"][$i]["total"]."</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="6" align="right">Total Due Amount</td>
<td>".$grandTotal."</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
"; {/php}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 in echo "<table border=1>"; not echo "<table border="1">";
```